# Bitcoin-qt attempts to load its old wallets. How can I configure it so that it does not do it?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-qt-setup

> Warning: Skipping -wallet path that doesn't exist. Failed to load database path '/home/jerzy/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/blank'. Path does not exist.

I get this warning anytime I launch it with `nohup ~/bitcoin/bin/bitcoin-qt --conf=/home/jerzy/.bitcoin/bitcoinT.conf &`.

The content of the respective configuration file is:

```
testnet=1
keypool=3
```

It seems that **bitcoin-qt** attempts to load old and non-existing in `.bitcoin/wallets` wallets, but only those created with **bitcoin-qt**, and not those
from with `bitcoin-cli`. From what file does **bitcoin-qt** get the information about the old wallets? How can I stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what file does bitcoin-qt get the information about the old wallets? How can I stop this behaviour?

```
/home/jerzy/.bitcoin/testnet3/settings.json
```

Open `settings` file and remove wallet name mentioned in error.